# Simulate Database access on .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, serialization, dll

I have an ASP.NET solution that consist of two different projects:
Project One is the ASP.NET pages, javascript and CSS. Project Two is an encapsulated DLL that is reference by project One, and have all the logic for database Accessing.

Basically, project One collect data and creates instances of classes defined on project Two, and call method on those classes that fisically access de database (inside Project Two code) and return object of type List of(ObjectType)

Now I need to send a copy of the project One to a third party programmer, but i don't want to send Databases, so my idea is to create a copy of project Two (a new DLL), that simulates database access but insted of get data from the database returns fixed data (hardcoded) in the exact same format.

So my question is: How can I Hardcode that data on the DLL without having to create object manualy one by one?.

My first attemp is to serialize an object already returned by a database to XML with this code:

```
Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter
Dim ser As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of User)))
ser.Serialize(sw, Users)

Debug.WriteLine(sw.ToString)
```

That creates an string with all the data. But it is possible to re-create the collection from this result? Is there a better way to do this? thanks!!!

Comment: Yes i could do that. But I need the XML content to be inside the DLL not in an external file (Hardcoded)

Comment: You can add string resources to your project. Solution explorer > right click project > Properties > Resources tab. Retrieve the resource with `string xml = Properties.Resources.YourResourceName;`